# Installing React Bootstrap - can't rseolve

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using npm install --save react-bootstrap
to install bootstrap.

The documentation also says to place import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in your index.js file which I have done.

I get an error.  Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

When I look in node_modules I am not seeing bootstrap anywhere.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both react-bootrap and bootstrap@4.6.0

```
> npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#installation

Comment: Before I installed react bootstrap I was able to use the import React from 'react'; statement.  After installing bootstrap I get Module not installed.  Even if I re-install React the import React from 'react'; complains about module not installed.  Whats going on with this?

Comment: I cannot confirm what is issues here, but I think you can try to verify ur project packge.json see whether under the dependencies got the  boostrap installed. And also ensures that import statement is correct